# Does using bitwise not operator (~) on boolean values invoke Undefined Behavior?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

If a C++ program applies the bitwise-not operator (~) to a boolean value, does that invoke Undefined Behavior?

E.g. is the following program well-defined?

```
bool f = false;
bool f2 = ~f;    // is f2 guaranteed to be true, or is this UB?
bool t = true;
bool t2 = ~t;    // is t2 guaranteed to be false, or is this UB?
```

(Yes, I know there is a ! operator that is better-suited to this sort of thing; for purposes of this question we will ignore its existence ;))

Comment: I'm guessing `~` promotes the argument to `int` before doing anything anyway, so ~0 would convert to `true`. Can't be 100% sure without looking.

Comment: @chris, you're right.

Comment: is it UB to do `bool b = 13;` [or something like that]?

Comment: @MatsPetersson: No, the `int` value `13` is implicitly converted to `bool`, yielding `true`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **5.3.1/10** The operand of `~` shall have integral or unscoped enumeration type; the result is the one’s complement of its operand. **Integral promotions are performed.** [emphasis mine]
>
> **4.5/6** A prvalue of type `bool` can be converted to a prvalue of type `int`, with `false` becoming zero and `true` becoming one.
>
> **4.5/7** These conversions are called *integral promotions*.

So `~false` is an `int` with a bit pattern consisting of all ones - one's complement of a bit pattern representing 0, namely all zeros (as required by **3.9.1/7**.) Similarly, `~true` is an `int` that's one's complement of the bit representation of 1 - namely, all ones with the least significant bit zero. Both these values will evaluate to `true` in boolean context.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Where does this standard say that? I was actually looking for that wording, and sadly failing. There's wording to this effect in C99 **6.2.6.2** - perhaps it could be argued that this wording is incorporated into C++ standard by reference, but that sounds like a pretty weak argument. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: @MattMcNabb Ah, right. "Pure binary numeration system" is the term of art I've forgotten about. Let me update the answer.

Comment: I guess there is a little bit of room to argue that negative-zero could be an alternate representation of `0` , in one's complement

Comment: @MattMcNabb C99, at least, puts a limitation on how a negative zero can be produced (basically, only by bit twiddling). Just writing `0` or `(int)false` shouldn't do it. But yes, C++ standard doesn't have any similar wording.

Answer (score 3):

The arithmetic operators perform the integral promotions on their operand. Specifically [expr.unary.op]/9 says that this happens for `~` too.

So `~t` is the same as `~1`. This gives a valid non-zero integer.

Integer-to-bool conversions are defined by [conv.bool]:

> A zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to false; any other value is converted to true

so `bool t2 = ~t;` yields `t2 == true`.  There is no undefined behaviour.

---

`~f` is the same as `~0`. In 2's complement, `~0` gives `-1`, so we will have `f2 == true`.

<sub>In 1's complement -- if there were ever a C++ system that uses 1's complement -- then the effect of `~0` is unclear.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

```
bool t = true;
bool t2 = ~t;    // is t2 guaranteed to be false, or is this UB?
```

I suppose it is not guaranteed, seeing how

```
  bool b = true;
  bool b1 = ~b;
  cout << b1;
```

outputs a "true"

I suppose it has to do with boolean representation... if it is a byte, then `00000001` will negate to `11111110` which is not zero. Promotion might also be at play, but it's the same tune.

The key here is it is "bitwise" not "logical". So one should not expect the two to match, unless the boolean representation is a single bit.

Easily entirely defined behavior.